# Why does Ckeditor show a removed tab in a dialog?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have removed the "Advanced"-tab of my Ckeditor table dialog but when I look at the properties of an existing table then the advanced tab is still there. In my `config.js` I have this

`config.removeDialogTabs = "image:advanced;table:advanced;link:advanced;link:target";`

When I create a new table then the "Advanced"-tab doesn't show but when I edit an existing table it is there. I'm using version 4.5.6. Why is a removed tab shown?

Here is a screen recording:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same dialog is actually defined twice with different names. The first one is called `table` and the other one is called `tableProperties`.

So you need to add `tableProperties:advanced` as well:

`config.removeDialogTabs = "image:advanced;table:advanced;tableProperties:advanced;link:advanced;link:target";`

Comment: This solved my problem. Now it's working as expected. Thanks!